# Statsmodel intercept is different to Seaborn lmplot intercept

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, seaborn, statsmodels

What could explain the difference in intercepts between statsmodel OLS regression and also seaborn lmplot?

My statsmodel code:

```
X = mmm_ma[['Xvalue']]
Y = mmm_ma['Yvalue']
model2 = sm.OLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), data=mmm_ma)
model_fit = model2.fit()
model_fit.summary()
```

My seaborn lmplot code:

```
sns.lmplot(x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue', data=mmm_ma)
```

My statsmodel intercept is 28.9775 and my seaborn lmplot's intercept is around 45.5.

### Questions

- Should the intercepts be the same?
- Why might explain why these are different? (can I change some code to make it equal)
- Is there a way to achieve a plot similar to seaborn lmplot but using the exact regression results to ensure they align?

### Edit

@Massoud thanks for posting that.  I think I have realised what is the problem.  My x-values range between 1400 to 2600 and y-values range from 40 to 70.  So using seaborn lmplot, it just plots the regression and the intercept is based on the lowest range X value - which is an intercept of 46.

[image]

However for statsmodel OLS, it keeps the line going until X = 0, which is why I get an intercept of 28 or so.

So I guess the question is there a way to continue the trend line using seaborn to go all the way until x = 0.

[image]

I tried changing the axis but it doesn't seem to extend the line.

```
axes = lm.axes
axes[0,0].set_xlim(0,)
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is weird. Maybe if you could provide more details we could help better. I tried to replicate the problem but I am getting the same intercepts from both approaches.

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

mmm_ma = {'Xvalue': range(0, 40), 'Yvalue': np.random.randint(low=0, high=40, size=40)}

mmm_ma = pd.DataFrame(mmm_ma)

X = mmm_ma[['Xvalue']]
Y = mmm_ma['Yvalue']
model2 = sm.OLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), data=mmm_ma)
model_fit = model2.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())


sns.lmplot(x='Xvalue', y='Yvalue', data=mmm_ma)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 Yvalue   R-squared:                       0.005
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.021
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.2071
Date:                Wed, 18 Jul 2018   Prob (F-statistic):              0.652
Time:                        00:51:04   Log-Likelihood:                -155.75
No. Observations:                  40   AIC:                             315.5
Df Residuals:                      38   BIC:                             318.9
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         17.2183      3.783      4.551      0.000       9.559      24.877
Xvalue         0.0760      0.167      0.455      0.652      -0.262       0.414
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        3.327   Durbin-Watson:                   1.618
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.189   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.738
Skew:                           0.197   Prob(JB):                        0.419
Kurtosis:                       2.058   Cond. No.                         44.5
==============================================================================
```

And below is the plot from Seaborn:
[image]

Comment: How is "I can't reproduce your problem" an answer? This should have been a comment asking for additional details and a flag for the question that it is lacking an MCVE.

Comment: @Massoud - thanks.  I have posted an update in the original post, looks like the intercept is different because the X axis didn't start at 0.  Is there an easy way to change this in Seaborn?

Comment: @dsnOwhiskey I am not sure if you can do that in Seaborn. If you are just looking for the intercept you can always use two points on the trendline and obtain the equation of that line which gives you the intercept and slope of the line.

Comment: Alright cool - thanks mate! I guess I won't be using seaborn then in this case!

Comment: @dsnOwhiskey I am still not sure but I just dug deep into the source codes of Seaborn on github and could not find anything there as well. I opened an issue there and asked him if he could add this feature.